# Customizing f6-key for fast "M-x imenu" + "Pr" + Enter

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-macros, imenu

I wish to customize my `f6`key so it corresponds to a fast way of doing `M-x imenu`, then `Pr RET`. I've added the following to my `~/.emacs`:
`(global-set-key [f6] 'imenu)`

Then I've tried to add different stuff after `'imenu`, but all has failed and I've tried to google Emacs forums and google, but didn't find an obvious solution.

When `M-x imenu` is started it gives the user 4 possibilities:
  2: *Rescan*
  3: Procedures
  4: Types
  5: Modules

I always want to go into `Procedures` so it's enough to type `Pr`
followed by `RET`. And that explains the full key-sequence: `M-x imenu`, then `Pr RET`.

How can I proceed from the `(global-set-key [f6] 'imenu)` step and make the `F6` key work as described above...

**UPDATE**: Thanks a lot so far (also for "pretty"-fying the question), however something new happened: Based on the answer from RichieHH I tried adding the following to my ~/.emacs file (although on a different system/computer, please bear over with that):

```
(fset 'lastMacro
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([120 31 escape 120 105 109 101 110 117] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(global-set-key [f5] 'lastMacro)


(fset 'yep
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([escape 120 105 109 101 110 117 return 109 97 105 110 return] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(global-set-key [f6] 'yep)
```

Thing thing is that now the F5-key works - but not the F6-key. If you want to use the same "test file" as I'm using, grab the example at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/orlp/pdqsort/master/bench/bench.cpp and then `M-x imenu` should allow to quickly jump to different sections in that file. The problem seems to be: I'm running the X11 version of emacs (didn't try terminal-only) and if I type `M-x imenu` a "text-menu" pops up. If I instead use the F5-key, a GUI/X11-menu pops up, at the mouse cursor location... And that's probably why the F6-key doesn't work... I appreciate if anyone could please explain that behaviour and if I'm doing something wrong (reading the answer incorrect)?

Answer (score 1):

Look up [emacs keyboard macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html)

You will record a sequence, save it resulting in a function, then bind that function to your f6 key.

Comment: Please elaborate. Otherwise this is essentially a link-only answer and so risks being deleted. Please summarize the info at the link that you think answers the question.

Comment: This is a link to official documents that explains all of the points. While I am not disagreeing, surely the refer to docs, and providing the link, is better here than cutting and pasting information that is up to date and properly maintained in the link I provided? Had I linked a random blog then yes, 100% with you.  I have outlined the three steps and referenced the supporting information. I kind of felt the pointer to "using macros" is the answer the OP is looking for rather than someone writing the code for him.

Comment: Yes, refer to the doc. No, do not ONLY refer to the doc. You have at least said to record a sequence, save it in a function, and bind it to a key, so your answer is not 100% link only. But please summarize what you think the doc says that specifically answers the question.

Comment: @RichieHH : Thanks a lot for leading me in the right direction, I'm grateful for that! However, maybe I'm misunderstanding something... Please see the updated question and I hope that behaviour can easily be reproduced on other systems.